# Colors of variable mathematica

Tags: color, variable-definitions, variable

Suppose that I have an equation which goes like this:

```
x = 2;
yp = 2;
y_p= 2;
a = x + yp + y_p;
```

Usually, once the variable is defined it will be of blue color and once it executed (by pressing Shift+ Enter) it will change color to black. But, you can see that x and yp change to black, but Subscript[y, p] still remain in the same color. Why is this so? Is it default in Mathematica that if you use the subscripts as variable, the color will not change after execution?

Comment: `Subscript[y, p]  = 2` creates definitions for `Subscript`, not `y` or `p`.

Comment: `y_p` is not subscript in MMA. Check the docs for `Blank`. The most common use of the construction `y_p` occurs when defining functions. `f[x_List]:=10*x` for instance. Where the `_List` indicates that f only applies to arguments with the head `List`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans, I got your point. If I could able to upload the screen shot, it could have been better, but I am not able to do so. Let me try to explain it in this way:
Actually, if you type 'y' and press Cntrl+_ and then write p, the output will show y with the subscript p. And then you try to do the Evaluation, that 
y-subscript-p will not change the color to black like all the other, but it will stay like that in blue color.
And, I am not talking about functions as such.